# Is there an ideal / idiomatic way to debug running plugins?

Tags: plugin-system, plugin-unite.vim, async

I sometimes have plugs stop working — in my case, mostly using async lookups with Unite.  When this happens, I would like to see what is happening and look into how to configure around it, or make a patch.

Is there a command that shows a 'log' of running errors?  I'm hoping for any place to get status.  Similarly, can I ping or probe plugins or a register they interact with, in order to watch a 'live stream' of events?

Comment: Suspect it won't be much help for Unite's async stuff, but, more generally, are you already aware of `:h debug-scripts`? It describes how to step through Vimscript command by command, and, if necessary, run ex commands as you go.